# R code to split a data into equal sized distinct samples

Tags: r, statistics

I am having trouble in writing the right  R code for obtaining 4 distinct samples of equal size out of a data set.

Need your help!

Thanks and Regards,
Reelina

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your goal is as to what you might want to try here. I am going to assume that given a data frame you want to create four subsets of equal size where each subset is a randomly sampled quarter of the data.

For demo purposes I have used the `Seatbelts` data included in base R as this has a number of rows that is a multiple of 4. This solution uses base R functions only. For more involved data frame manipulation I suggest looking at the `dplyr` package.

```
# use seat belts data as example as it has nrow(x) %% 4 == 0
data(Seatbelts)
# generate a random sample of numbers 1:4 such that each occurs equally
ind = sample(rep(1:4,each = nrow(Seatbelts)/4))
# you could add that as a column to your data frame allowing the groups to be
# specified in formulae etc
# or if you want the four subsets
lapply(split(1:nrow(Seatbelts),ind), function(i) Seatbelts[i,])
```

If your data is a vector then this is easier

```
x = runif(24)
ind = sample(rep(1:4,each = length(x)/4))
split(x,ind)
```

If you don't want random sampling then just create `ind` as

```
ind = rep(1:4,each = length(x)/4)
```

and split in the same way as before.

You should be careful using things like `cut` as this will not give you 4 subsets of equal size necessarily.

```
table(as.numeric(cut(x,4)))

# 1 2 3 4 
# 7 6 3 8
```

This is because `cut` cuts the range of x into intervals rather than it's length.

Comment: No problem, if it solves your issue you should accept the answer so that future searchers can see that it has been solved. If you want to use external packages `caret::createFolds` can do the same job as a single function call without worrying about specifying all the extra stuff above.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
# Create data for example
x <- data.frame(id = 1:100, y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))

# Returns a list with four equally sized distinct samples of the data
lapply(split(sample(nrow(x)), ceiling((1:nrow(x))/25)), function(i) x[i, ])
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the cut command:

```
x<-1:100
cutindex<-cut(x, breaks=4)
```

To rename the cut points use the "levels" command:

```
levels(cutindex)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Once the data has been cut, I would suggest using the group_by command from the dplyr package for additional analysis.

Comment: This does not give equal sized groups